# Zend Cloud Infrastructure InstanceList - How to iterate through the list in the view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm currently working on an Zend app which would control my Amazon EC2 instances through a simple web interface.

I was good until I arrived here:

```
$ec2 = $this->initEC2()->getEC2();

$instances = $ec2->listInstances();

$this->assign('instances', $instances);
```

Here's the code from my custom controller `Action.php`:

```
public function initEC2()
{
    $key    = MW_Config::AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
    $secret = MW_Config::AWS_SECRET_KEY;
    $region = 'us-east-1';

    $infrastructure = Zend_Cloud_Infrastructure_Factory::getAdapter(array(
        Zend_Cloud_Infrastructure_Factory::INFRASTRUCTURE_ADAPTER_KEY => 'Zend_Cloud_Infrastructure_Adapter_Ec2',
        Zend_Cloud_Infrastructure_Adapter_Ec2::AWS_ACCESS_KEY => $key,
        Zend_Cloud_Infrastructure_Adapter_Ec2::AWS_SECRET_KEY => $secret,
        Zend_Cloud_Infrastructure_Adapter_Ec2::AWS_REGION     => $region,
    ));

    $this->ec2 = $infrastructure;

    return $this;
}

public function getEC2()
{
    if ($this->ec2 === null) {
        $this->initEC2();
    }

    return $this->ec2;
}
```

I would like to know how I iterate correctly through the instance list to get a table in the view script???

I tried a `while()`, a `for()` and a `foreach()` but nothing was working... I browsed the code of `Zend_Cloud_Insfrastructure_InstanceList` ([InstanceList.php](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/files/Cloud.Infrastructure.InstanceList.html#%5CZend_Cloud_Infrastructure_InstanceList)) but I didn't find anything concluent...

Comment: Var_dump the variable you want to iterate through & see what is inside it. Post back result here. It may not be directly iterable

Comment: You can see the Pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/wzSYEZAQ

Comment: Where is your loop example?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it appears that the class implements iterator interface [PHP Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)

You can do something like this:

```
foreach($it as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Try to get 1 result first, using current:

```
var_dump($instances->current());
```

Comment: `var_dump($this->instances->current());` = `Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /Users/fmarcoux/Documents/ZF/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Cloud/Infrastructure/InstanceList.php on line 105

NULL`

Comment: Sorry, don't use the property, use the method. i.e. getInstances()

Comment: What you mean by 'use the method'? `$this->instances->getInstances()` ?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? i.e. phpstorm, netbeans etc? These will help you  develop code, as you type it will display available methods, i.e set*, get* etc. From your var_dump, the properties are protected, so you will not be able to access them directly, but will have to use available methods (public functions within the class)